# Why does the following diagram induced by $f$ commute?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was reading Hatcher's Algebraic Topology. In section 2.2. on page 136, there is the following diagram,

Suppose $f : S^n \to S^n$, $n>0$, has the property that for some point $y \in S^n$, the preimage $f^{-1}(y)$ consists of only finitely many points, say  $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$. Let $U_1,\dots, U_m$ be disjoint neighbourhoods of these points, mapped by $f$ into a neighbourhood $V$ of $y$. Then $f\left(U_i - x_i\right) \subset V- y$ for each $i$, and we have a diagram

[image]

where all the maps are the obvious ones, and in particular $k_i$ and $p_i$ are induced by inclusions, so the triangles and squares commute. The two isomorphisms in the upper half of the diagram comes from excision, while the lower two isomorphisms come from exact sequences of pairs.

I have worked out all the single arrows in the above diagram. The question is that why does the diagram commute? The main obstruction to proving that this diagram commutes is to write down the isomorphism in the above diagram explicitly. There are so many maps in the diagram.

Comment: This diagram already commutes at the level of maps of pairs, so the diagram in homology commutes by functoriality.

Comment: @Thorgott thank you ,the problem is the isomorphism for example the excision is defined in a complicated way ,how to define the map in the level of maps of pairs

Comment: The excision isomorphism is not defined in a complicated way, it's induced by the inclusion.

Comment: aha,I see thank you